# RSpec shared_examples conditionally check for block presence

Tags: ruby, rspec

Problem:
I am attempting to create a shared example that has a series of base tests and conditionally can run a few more tests if a `let` was declared in the block.

Background:
I have a response object that is used as the return value for service objects. It has a `payload`, which by default is an empty hash but it can contain data if the service sets them.

Using a shared example, I can easily cover the base case when a `payload` is not present. However, some services populate the payload. Given that the payload often references variables defined by `let` statements, I opted to share the context through a block instead of passing in parameters to the shared context.

Here is what I would like to do, I have mimicked the behavior with doubles so that this snippet is valid and can be used to test. The subject double represents the service object, and execute returns a double representing the response object.

```rb
RSpec.describe 'conditional shared_examples' do
  shared_examples_for 'a successful Service' do
    let(:response) { subject.execute }

    it 'returns a success ServiceResponse' do
      expect(response.success?).to be(true)
    end

    it 'contains the payload from the service', if: payload do
      expect(response.payload).to eq(payload)
    end
  end

  describe 'base shared_examples without a block' do
    subject { double(execute: double(success?: true)) }

    it_behaves_like 'a successful Service'
  end

  describe 'when a block is provided' do
    subject { double(execute: double(success?: true, payload: { foo: 'bar' })) }

    it_behaves_like 'a successful Service' do
      let(:payload) { { foo: 'bar' } }
    end
  end
end
```

This fails because `payload` is not available for the conditional check, here is the error:

```
NameError:
  undefined local variable or method `payload'
```

This makes sense to me, `payload` is not available at the `ExampleGroup` level, it is only available from within an `example`.

Questions:

Is there a way to check if a block was passed or if a method has been defined through `let` at the ExampleGroup level?

How can I conditionally check if this `it_behaves_like` was passed a block or has a specific `let` method declared?

Comment: you can place `if` right into the expectation row

Comment: Ah, yes. I think that's a simple workaround. I had a similar situation where you can access shared_examples parameters from the ExampleGroup context so I was trying to mimic that. But maybe I'm just overcomplicating it.